# Unity integration with Ionic distorting model on iOS devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, ionic-framework, ionic5, glblendfunc

We have recently developed a Unity app and integrated this with an existing Ionic app. We load models into Unity via URLs and we are facing an issue with the model being distorted on iOS devices. This issue is only with GLB files and not FBX files. When testing the app using the PlaceAtLocation module in Xcode the model appears as it should. However, after integrating with Ionic the model is distorted and almost squished. Could anybody help with this at all please?

Please find link to videos https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/tsmfzbvd8nkfqwgk8uf1q/h?dl=0&rlkey=lliw0lnfmunm1euv2hcu7j46.

We have tried multiple workarounds but had no luck in solving the issue. Unity have not responded to our questions.

Comment: Your best bet is to wait for Unity's response since you want to combine Unity Into Ionic. This has nothing to do with an Ionic issue.